# Android app dev my first app example error

Tags: android

I have searched everywhere but cannot find an answer to my problem.  I am totally new to this and am in way over my head.  I am simply doing the basic "my first app tutorial" from the Android dev site.  The tutorial causes errors even though the code is exactly as written in the example.  The error that shows up in the console is:

```
[2013-03-12 15:33:36 - MyFirstApp] D:\Android Development\MyFirstApp\res\menu       \main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
[2013-03-12 15:34:38 - MyFirstApp] W/ResourceType( 6352): Bad XML block: header size     311 or total size 5346560 is larger than data size 0
```

The only things I changed was what the tutorial told me to change.  `Activity_main.xml` and `strings.xml`. I never changed anything in `main.xml`. In the package explorer it shows a red x next to `MainActivity>onCreate(Bundle)` and `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)`  Here is the code from MainActiviy with errors in parenthesis

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); (error here red underline under R)
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); (error here red underline under R)
    return true;
}
```

}

What did I do wrong? I just started learning this and I can't even seem to get the tutorial to run right!

Here is the Activity_main.xml and strings.xml that I changed following the directions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please make sure the API Version configured in Project.properties is comptatible with you code

Comment: Are you sure your strings.xml is right? Looks wrong to me.

Comment: In Eclipse, use the Problems window to help track down catastrophic failures like this.  When `R cannot be resolved to a variable` it can be something as simple as a typo in an XML file or more complex like missing resources or libraries.  Ignore the `R` errors they will go away after you fix the root problem.

Comment: is there a action_settings value in your strings.xml?

Comment: Do you have any errors in any of your XML files? If not, try cleaning your project

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I redid the exercise step by step and discovered a discrepancy between the lesson and the Android example file MyFirstApp.  The tutorial has wrong string name in the strings.xml lesson.  So if you follow the directions and type exactly what it tells you to you will receive an error. The discrepancy is in strings.xml under <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>.  In the lesson they tell you to write <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string> this causes the no resource error.  Hope this helps someone else.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

as in Console log :

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with
>   value '@string/action_settings

means you will need to add an `action_settings` string inside `res/values/strings.xml` file as

```
<resources>
    <!-- Your other strings -->
    <string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, but the XML has some issues.

1. Your code refers to activity_main, but the filename you used is Activity_main. Because the matching is case-sensitive, Android recommends that you use lowercase-only in file names.
2. You seem to have listed Activity_main.xml twice. Strings.xml isn't there at all. For that reason, it's impossible to tell what the problem is.
3. You didn't list any of the files in your res/menu directory. If you're creating an options menu, you need res/menu/menu.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Android programming myself but will try to help anyway.

R is usually automatically generated; a red line underneath it usually indicates it has disappeared.

A majority of the time you will receive this error because you have made an error in you String.xml file.

Based on your error message, it seems as though there is an error with the string for "action_settings". Ensure you have not included any apostrophes or made any other syntax errors.